# How to Tweet to Twitter API 1.1 with .NET using No external Libraries

Tags: .net, api, twitter, twitterizer

I would like to be able to Tweet to the Twitter API 1.1 with .NET using No external Libraries. Tweeting is pretty much all I am looking to do besides seeing the success status of the tweet and/or if it was successful connecting to twitter.

I would prefer a solution in VB.Net, but C# would be ok.

I have tested an application using an external library called twitterizer, and I can tweet just fine, but twitterizer  only supports API 1.0 which is being deprecated in about a month.

Thanks.

Comment: Just Twitterizer, so far I was hoping to get some more ideas here.

Comment: you can take a look to linq to twitter code and take some of impl they got as far as I know that works with 1.1 http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067996/authenticate-and-request-a-users-timeline-with-twitter-api-1-1-oauth/17071447#17071447

Comment: Yea, in the end I decided to go with linqtotwitter. It seems well supported, though overkill a little overkill for what I am doing.